Conditional limit theorem for method of types with explicit bounds in terms of n
A lot of large deviation theory is only concerned seemingly with the asymptotic nature of certain probabilities. Mainly because I imagine most applications have $n$ so big that lower order terms are irrelevant.
However, there is a non-asymptotic bound version of Sanov's theorem that says if $E$ is a closed convex set of probability measures then the probability that an iid sequence distributed according to $Q$ of length $n$ will lie in $E$ is bounded above by $e^{-nD_{KL}(P* |Q)}$ where $P* \in E$ minimizes the KL-divergence from $Q$ among all types in $E$. This holds as far as I know at least in the finite alphabet case which is the one i'm interested in.
There is a similar theorem that says that the conditional distribution given a large deviation takes place will be close to the type with the minimum KL-divergence from $Q$ which lies in the set of types which are considered to deviate.
However, as these theorems all mainly belong to large deviation theory, there doesn't seem to be many explicit bounds given. And even though the conditional limit theorem is stated as a convergence in probability, there is also no bound given in terms of $n$.
My question is where should I look to find these sorts of theorems if I want explicit bounds on say the probability that the type of a sequence is within $\epsilon$-KL-divergence of a 'typical type' given that said type belongs to a particular set of types $A$.
